# server side Datatable mrender - invoke knockout function in viewmodel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I need to bind `onclick` event to my function in `viewmodel`.

```
{
    mData: "data", bSearchable: false, bSortable: false,
    mRender: function (data, type, full) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            return '<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-bind="click: getsomethingFunction"><span class="badge bg-color-blue txt-color-white">Yes</span></a>'
        }
        else
            return '<span >No</span>'
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the code, `getsomethingFunction` function will never get call. Anything that i missed out?

Comment: How are you injecting your HTML string into the DOM? If you're not using a `template` binding, you'll have to `ko.applyBindings` on your new elements...

Comment: Yes, I have ko.applyBingins for the entire index.html page. But this datatable only get initialized upon user action. May I know how to inject the new row to the DOM? how to bind the ko onclick function to my datatable row?

Comment: When you inject HTML _after_ you've called `applyBindings`, knockout does not automatically know what's going on. I'd suggest looking in to `fnRowCallback` to data-bind the new HTML. Other than that, you should provide a more complete example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)